# Taylor expansion of $h(x)=\sqrt{4+x^2}-3x-\frac{2}{x}$ at $x=-\infty $. Is Wolfram wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I did the taylor expansion at $-\infty $ of $$h(x)=\sqrt{4+x^2}-3x-\frac{2}{x}$$ and I found $$h(x)=-4x-\frac{4}{x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right).$$
But [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series%20%28sqrt%284%2Bx%5E2%29-3x-2%2Fx%29%2C%20x%3D-infty) says $$h(x)=-2x+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right).$$

I draw the graph of $f$ and my result looks correct. Am I wrong or Wolfram is wrong ? It the first time I see wolfram wrong, that's why I would like a confirmation from you.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Besides Daniel Fischer's answer to see why this happened, you can also confirm it... with Wolfram, after changing $x\to-\infty$ by $y\to\infty$ (replace $y$ by $-x$ in the [end result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5B+sqrt%5B4%2By%5E2%5D%2B3y%2B2%2Fy%2C+%7By%2CInf%2C2%7D%5D))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wolfram interprets the input in a different way, not what you intended. Below the series expansion, there is a "(Laurent series)", which means Wolfram outputs the Laurent expansion of the function around $\infty$ (the point at infinity of the complex or real projective line), using the branch

$$x\sqrt{1 + \frac{4}{x^2}}$$

of $\sqrt{4+x^2}$ in a neighbourhood of $\infty$ rather than the nonnegative real $\lvert x\rvert \sqrt{1 + \frac{4}{x^2}}$ as you intended.

Comment: Funny artifact of this: because of that, [the limit and the Laurent series given by Wolfram seem contradictory.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+%28sqrt%284%2Bx%5E2%29-3x-2%2Fx%29%2F%284x%29+at+x%3D-Inf)

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, but as you said, we bother are true ? strange...

Comment: @Rick You and Wolfram Alpha are doing different things, so you can both be right although you have different results. Basically, Wolfram Alpha takes the negative square root of $\sqrt{4+x^2}$ near $-\infty$ instead of the positive square root that you intended. It does that because from the complex analysis standpoint, the meromorphic branch of $\sqrt{4+x^2}$ on a neighbourhood of $\infty$ that takes positive values for large positive values of $x$ takes negative values for negative $x$ of large modulus.